# Normal family and arithmetic progression

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-dynamics

It is basic fact that for a holomorphic (or mermorphic) map $f$, the family of iterates $\{f^n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, is normal if and only if  $\{f^{mn}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, is normal $\forall m\geq 1$.

For a sequence of integers $\{n_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$,
There is natural question to ask under which condition:

$\{f^{n_i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is a normal family implies  $\{f^{i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is a normal family.

We just know a obvious condition: for $i$ sufficiently large, $\{n_i\}$ is arithmetic progression.  It is natural to ask whether this condition is optimal in some sense?

Any reference and comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true for every subsequence. Indeed, if $z$ is on the set of normality
(where $f^n$ is normal), then evidently every subset of $f^n$ is normal. If $z$ is on
the Julia set, then there is a repelling periodic point in every neighborhood of $z$.
At a repelling periodic point, any subsequence of iterates is evidently not normal.

Comment: Thank you, professor. Can we use Marty criterion to prove it (not use the fact repelling periodic points are dense in Julia sets.)?